# How can I Get a List in cshtml.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages, syncfusion

I'm using a razor pages. I have on list of permissions, and this list have prop of treeview.

```
permissions.Add(new Paccess { id = "All", name = "Acesso Total", expanded = true, haschildren = true, ischecked = true });
permissions.Add(new Paccess { id = "G", name = "Geral", expanded = false, haschildren = false, ischecked = true, parent = "All" });
permissions.Add(new Paccess { id = "U", name = "Gestão de Utilizadores", expanded = false, haschildren = false, ischecked = true, parent = "All" });
permissions.Add(new Paccess { id = "E", name = "Gestão de Equipamentos", expanded = false, haschildren = false, ischecked = true, parent = "All" });
```

In my cshtml I have this treeView

```
<ejs-dialog id="default_dialog" isModal="true" width="500px" visible="false" showCloseIcon="true" header="Acessos">
    <e-content-template>
        <form method="post" style="padding:1em">
            <ejs-treeview id="listdata" name="permissions" TValue="Paccess" showCheckBox="true" nodeClicked="nodeCheck" autoCheck="true">
                <e-treeview-fields TValue="Paccess" dataSource="@Model.permissions" text="name" name="permissions" id="id" parentId="parent" hasChildren="haschildren" expanded="expanded" IsChecked="ischecked"></e-treeview-fields>
            </ejs-treeview>
            <button class="button special pull-right" asp-page-handler="Save">Teste</button>
        </form>                            
    </e-content-template>
</ejs-dialog>
```

I want, when I click in Teste, get the list in my cshtml.cs.

---

Paccess class:

```
public class Paccess 
{
    public string? id { get; set; } 
    public string? name { get; set; } 
    public bool haschildren { get; set; } 
    public string? parent { get; set; } 
    public bool expanded { get; set; } 
    public bool ischecked { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: The code cannot run as provided. Please provide a sample that includes the `Paccess` class and the type of `permissions`

Comment: Without looking closer, it looks like you are setting `parent` as the `parentId`, but the top node has an id of `All`

Comment: @Jonathan 
My Paccess - class: [IMG] https://prnt.sc/26q8l3t
My List - public List<Paccess> permissions = new();

I want click in my button and get all the list in my method

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of your code; copy the code and paste it into your question as text.

Comment: ´´´public class Paccess
    {
        public string? id { get; set; }
        public string? name { get; set; }
        public bool haschildren { get; set; }
        public string? parent { get; set; }
        public bool expanded { get; set; }
        public bool ischecked { get; set; }
    }´´´ @Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

In TreeView, we have getTreeData method which will retrieve the updated data source of TreeView. If you pass the ID of TreeView node as arguments for this method, then it will return the updated data source of the corresponding node otherwise it will return the entire updated data source of TreeView. Check the below code snippet.

```
<button class="button special pull-right" id="normalbtn" asp-page-handler="Save">Teste</button>
...
document.getElementById('normalbtn').onclick = function () {
    var treeview = document.getElementById("listdata").ej2_instances[0];
    //Here you can get the updated datasource.
    var data = treeview.getTreeData();
}
```

Comment: What I needed myself, is to pass this list<Paccess> my Model.permissions, when I click the button and receive in my method, will it be possible?
@Indhumathy Method in razor pages c#

Comment: @MarcoOliveira, Do you want to retrieve the entire List within a method call of button click on the razor page?